# If the lower Darboux integral is zero, does the function equal zero for every x?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

So say I let a function $f$ be a continuous function on the interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)$ is greater than or equal to $0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$. If $L(f) = 0$, does $f(x)=0$ for every $x$ in $[a,b]$?

I was thinking to use a proof by contradiction, and assume if $L(x) = 0$ then $f(x)$ does not equal $0$ for every $x$ in $[a, b]$. I was hoping I could then show that if this was true, then $f(x)$ would not be integrable and therefore not continuous as every continuous function on $[a,b]$ is integrable (thus a contradiction as $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$). Is this on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier approach is as follows: show that if $f$ is continuous and $f(c) > 0$ for some $c \in [a,b]$, show that $L(f)$ can't be zero.

In particular, use the continuity of $f$ to find a neighborhood $U$ containing $c$ for which $f(x)>0$ for every $x \in U$.  Use this to find a lower bound for $L(f)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach (if I understand it correctly) should work.  Find a point $a$ such that $f(a) = y> 0$, and use continuity to find an interval around $a$ such that $f(x) > \frac{y}{2}$ in this interval.  Then show that the upper Darboux integral $U(f) \ge \frac{y}{2} d$ where $d$ is the length of the integral, which means $U(f) > L(f)$ so $f$ is not integrable.  Implying $f$ is not continuous.